# How to declare an array with a vector

Tags: c++

Hey everyone I'm trying to get an array working with a vector so my code stops coming up with the letter "word" every time you run my program. I assume I need to do something with the vectors but i've read a few guides but I'm pretty confused if somebody could help me with the steps that would be great? :)

EDIT: Basically I'm trying to get my vectors to work with the function playGame(); so that I can show different words instead of just having the same word come up every time aka "Word"

Here's my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int playGame(string word); 
string array[]= { "apple", "banana", "orange", "strawberry" }; 
vector<string> word (array, array+4); 

int main() 
{
int choice;
bool menu = true;
do{
cout <<"Please select one of the following options:  \n";

cout << "1: Play\n"
    "2: Help\n"
    "3: Quit\n";

cout << "Enter your selection (1, 2 and 3): ";
cin >> choice;
//*****************************************************************************
// Switch menu to display the menu.
//*****************************************************************************
    switch (choice)
 {
      case 1:
        cout << "You have chosen play\n";
        //int playGame(string word); 
        playGame("word");
        break;
     case 2:
        cout << "You have chosen help\n";
        cout << "Here is a description of the game Hangman and how it is    played:\nThe      word to guess is represented by a row of dashes, giving the number of letters, numbers and category. If the guessing player suggests a letter or number which occurs in the word, the other player writes it in all its correct positions";
        break; 
         case 3:
        cout << "You have chosen Quit, Goodbye.";
        break;
    default:
        cout<< "Your selection must be between 1 and 3!\n";

    }

}while(choice!=3);    
getchar();
getchar();


cout << "You missed " << playGame("programming");
cout << " times to guess the word programming." << endl;
}
```

Comment: please be more specific. what exactly do you want to achieve with "getting an array work with a vector"? also, please only show *relevant* parts of the code. like this it is a guessing game what you might have meant

Comment: Try that is that more helpful? Sorry I'm new to this all and trying to figure out what code is relevant.

Comment: Your code `vector<string> word (array, array+4);` is the correct way to declare a vector which is a copy of an array. So if you are having trouble then it must be somewhere else. What's not clear to me at all is why you think switching from an array to a vector will help. Perhaps you coupld explain why you think it will.

Comment: Looking again I think the issue is that you want to know how to choose the word to play with from the array (or vector). Whether you use an array or a vector is completely irrelevent to that question. So perhaps you need to rephrase things, explain what you are trying to do (choose a different word each time), don't try and explain how you think you should do that (because that bit's just wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vectors are not part of the answer. You can make this work with arrays or vectors. The issue (as I understand it) is that you want to choose a random word from your list of words. Here's how to do that using an array

```
int main() 
{
    size_t sizeOfArray = sizeof array/sizeof array[0]; // calculate the
                                                       // size of the array
    srand(time(0)); // set up random number generator

    ...

       case 1:
           cout << "You have chosen play\n";
           playGame(array[rand()%sizeOfArray]); // pick a random word
           break;
```

Comment: Where do I define Array exactly? It's giving me errors on array/sizeof

Comment: +1 for your psychic powers discovering what OP wanted to ask ;)

Comment: Yeah thanks for the help man but I'm not sure why array next to size of is giving me the undefined error :/

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, assuming we decidce to play, your code does this

```
playGame("word");
```

In other words, you always send the word `"word"` to the function `playGame`, so therefore it always uses the word `word`. Randomly selecting a different word from a collection of words would clearly give you a variety of words in each game rather than the same word over and over.

Whe you say

```
I'm trying to get my vectors to work with the function playGame();
```

I presume you mean the `playGame(string word)` function rather than some other function you don't show us.

Having chosen a random index into your vector, say `index` just change your call to the playGame function as follows.
    playGame(word[index]);

This will index into the array you have called word, rather than the word `"word"`

Of course, this means the array isn't needed and certainly doesn't need to be global and the vector of words can be decalred inside the main function rather than at global scope.